# how to replace a word with *** in awk (unix)

Tags: unix, awk

I have some requests like below in one file. I want to replace the data after "password" to "****" . I tried using the below command. But i am not able to do it. can you suggest how it should be done?

request file contains as below:

```
->->->->->->->-> 07/06/11 13:26:21 cp 2191444 pp 2134056
qid 2097161 qtyp 1005
C0dJ 2907100211ADVVM1  00^ZLTBLTBLTB          HSM_S2^^KMKEYTYPE^Y605^^KMKEYDATE^Y01012000^^MEMBERNO^Y^^OCISPTY^Y00
70002643^^KMIV^Y^^ENCTOKEN^Y^^PASSWORD^Y1152^^CHANCODE^Y003^^SELLGENT^Y004^^SECLVLCD^Y005^^USRSRVDT^Y006^^USRSRVTM
^Y001^^PWDSRVDT^Y002^^PWDSRVTM^Y010^^PASSEFFDT^Y009^^
```

But the word after the password i.e. chancode  is not constant and the delimiter should be there even after changing.

I tried using below command:

```
awk -F"PASSWORD^" '{f1=$1; f2=$2; sub(substr(f2,1,index(f2,"^")-1),"****",f2); print f1 "PASSWORD^" f2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the * eg `\*` for each one? so `\*\*\*\*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Primitive, but works!:

```
sed -e "s/PASSWORD.*CHANCODE/PASSWORD\*\*\*\*CHANCODE/g" pass.txt
```